# Adding items to a datagrid [advice needed]

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagrid

I am used to working with listview in vb.Net where to add items you just use as an example:

```
ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr("Box start").ToString())
```

However, I cannot find a way to add items or sub-items to a datagrid via intellisense. All the googling I have done just throws up DataGridView which is the newer control, but I am only interested in DataGrid. If anyone could offer any advice or tuts I would be grateful. many thanks

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate whether this is a desktop app or a web app. That will help you get attention from people who can help.

Comment: Sorry, this is winforms. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily want to add items to a `DataGridView`, you want to add (or edit, remove, in some way make changes to) items to the *underlying data source* to which the `DataGridView` is *bound*.

For example, if you have a `Person` class and you bind the `DataGridView` to a `List(Of Person)`, it might look something like this:

```
Dim personList As New List(Of Person)()

' elsewhere...
personList = GetPeople()
dataGridView1.DataSource = personList
```

At this point, you manage the elements in `personList`, not the `DataGridView` itself.  So to add an element:

```
Dim newPerson As New Person()
' set some values on newPerson

personList.Add(newPerson)
```

You may need to "refresh" the `DataGridView` to reflect the changes:

```
dataGridView1.Refresh()
```

or:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
dataGridView1.DataSource = personList
```

Comment: David, are the controls the same for a datagrid? Thanks

Comment: @user1532468: The members look pretty similar in the documentation, yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx

Comment: david, is there to the best of your knowledge, any tuts or comprehensive instructions for an example of working with datagrid as I am new user to vb.net. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468: Not that I know of off-hand.  Your Google searches would be just as effective as mine in that regard.  I haven't done WinForms development in a very long time, so haven't needed to look up any such tutorials.